# Can Magnesium sulfate be mixed with NPK

Tags: fertilizer, nutrients, deficiency

Does magnesium compete with Potassium?

I see several fertilizers that have Potassium and Magnesium at the same time, so I'm wondering if I could safely mix magnesium sulfate with an NPK fertilizer.

Otherwise, would it be better to give them separately to the plant, within a week interval for example?

Comment: Mg + K is unlikely to be a problem, but you might have problems with Magnesium + Phosphate, if the soluble phosphates in the original fertilizer and the soluble magnesium salts react to form insoluble magnesium phosphate.

Answer (score 2):

NPK in not a composition. However fertilizer applications are relatively dilute compared to the mass of soil to which they are applied , so it is difficult to imagine a problem. Generally not a problem for a home owner depending on the exact levels and compositions of the NPK, but the mixed fertilizers can interact. I remember once getting a weak ammonia smell from dry mixed materials before application.